# Async method not able to return bool value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

```
private void ValidatePolicy (string PolicyNumber)
{
  var ispolicyvalid = this.IsPolicyExistInADCAsync(PolicyNumber);  
  if(ispolicyvalid) // here I am getting error
  {
    // some logic happens here 
  }
}
```

This is my code here I am getting an error - cannot implicitly convert type `system.threading.tasks.task<bool>` to `bool`.

```
public async Task<bool> IsPolicyExistAsync(string policyNumber)
{
    var accountId = await this.GetAccountId(policyNumber);
    return accountId != null;
}

public async Task<string> GetAccountId(string accountReference)
{
    // some more logic here

    return accountId;
}
```

I tried following approaches

**Option 1**

```
var ispolicyvalid = this.IsPolicyExistAsync(policyDetails.CorrectPolicyNumber).Result;
```

If I try this approach I get another error - replace task.result with await

**Option 2**

```
private void ValidatePolicy (string PolicyNumber)
{
  var ispolicyvalid = this.IsPolicyExistInADCAsync(PolicyNumber);  
  if(ispolicyvalid) 
  {
    // some logic happens here 
  }
}

public bool IsPolicyExistAsync(string policyNumber)
{
    var accountId = this.GetAccountId(policyNumber);
    return accountId != null;
}
```

In this approach there is no error, but `ispolicyvalid` is always false, because `GetAccountId()` method still awaiting result hence `accountId`  will not be null value – its false result
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cannot implicitly convert type system.threading.tasks.task to bool

That implies that `IsPolicyExistInADCAsync()` is an `async` method, or at least *awaitable* method that returns a `Task`.  (The code shown doesn't include this method, but includes methods similar to it which are themselves `async`, so it's pretty likely this one is as well.)

Basically, you would do *exactly what the code already does* in the `IsPolicyExistAsync()` method that you're showing.  Make the method `async`:

```
private async Task ValidatePolicy(string PolicyNumber)
```

And `await` the asynchronous operation therein:

```
var ispolicyvalid = await this.IsPolicyExistInADCAsync(PolicyNumber);
```

And of course, anything which calls `ValidatePolicy()` will also need to `await` its result.

Comment: As per the suggestion I made the changes , unfortunately still its not working.

private async Task ValidatePolicy(string policynumber)
{
  var ispolicyvalid = await this.IsPolicyExistAsync(PolicyNumber);

}

There are no errors, but below method is still waiting for result – due to that I get the accountId is not null – its false result.

public async Task<bool> IsPolicyExistAsync(string policyNumber)
{
    var accountId = await this.GetAccountId(policyNumber);
    return accountId != null;
}

Comment: @Kumas: "is still waiting for result" doesn't describe a problem.  If you want the result of an asynchronous operation then you would await that result.  So what *specifically* is the problem?  If you are expecting `accountId != null` to be `true` but it is `false` then, when you debug, what is `accountId`?  What did you expect it to be?  Why?  According to the code shown, that method does "some more logic here". We don't know what that logic is. But if you have some other code not shown here which is producing an unexpected result not described here, that's *probably* a new separate question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, sorry it was my mistake - I forget to add await on the calling method for "ValidatePolicy" that fixed my issue, once you again thank you

Answer (score 3):

> I am getting an error - cannot implicitly convert type system.threading.tasks.task to bool

Because `if` requires `bool`, not `Task<bool>` retuned by `IsPolicyExistInADCAsync`. Change `ValidatePolicy` to `async Task`:

```
private async Task ValidatePolicy (string PolicyNumber)
{
    var ispolicyvalid = await IsPolicyExistInADCAsync(PolicyNumber);  
    if(ispolicyvalid) // here I am getting error
    {
        // some logic happens here 
    }
}
```

> but ispolicyvalid is always false

Yes, because methods returning tasks do not (usually) return null's. And async state machine should always result in not-nullable `Task`.

Read also:

- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
- [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (why you should avoid calling `Task<T>.Result`, also check out info about [`GetAwaiter().GetResult()`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html#getawaitergetresult))

Comment: As per the suggestion I made the changes , unfortunately still its not working.

private async Task ValidatePolicy(string policynumber)
{
  var ispolicyvalid = await this.IsPolicyExistAsync(PolicyNumber);

}

There are no errors, but below method is still waiting for result – due to that I get the accountId is not null – its false result.

public async Task<bool> IsPolicyExistAsync(string policyNumber)
{
    var accountId = await this.GetAccountId(policyNumber);
    return accountId != null;
}

Comment: I am good now, thank you for your suggestion - I forget to add await on the calling method for "ValidatePolicy" that fixed my issue